# Formulario de imagenes en Access

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

Tengo un campo en una tabla de Access de tipo Datos adjuntos donde almaceno varias imágenes para un mismo registro. Necesito presentar en un formulario todas las imágenes asociadas a un registro, de tal manera que se puedan visualizar 4 ó 5 imágenes a la vez, es decir, que más o menos necesitaría que en la ventana del formulario se puedieran visualizar las imágenes como lo hace el explorador de Windows cuando presentas una carpeta de imágenes con las vista de iconos muy grandes.

¿Alguien sabe cómo lo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero, **yo no recomiendo usar el tipo de datos adjuntos porque suelen sobrecargar la base**. Y cuando una base en Access pesa mucho, se ejecuta más lento, **y puede acabar corrompiéndose con 2 GB de peso**. Recomiendo usar hipervínculos a carpetas donde tengas las imágenes y demás, pero que los archivos adjuntos estén fuera de la propia base.

Ahora, respecto a tu consulta, una forma sencilla de solucionarlo sería usando 2 tablas: En una tabla tendrías la información de los registros, excluyendo los datos adjuntos. Luego, en una tabla secundaria, relacionada con la primera, tendrías los archivos adjuntos asociados a cada registro de la tabla principal, poniendo únicamente 1 archivo adjunto por registro en esta tabla secundaria, pero creando todos los que necesites (si tienes 6 imágenes, pues crea 6 registros en esta tabla secundaria, asociados al registro que te interese en la tabla principal).

Tras esta explicación liosa, te pongo mi ejemplo.

He creado una base muy sencillita. Tengo una tabla principal que se llama MIS_REGISTROS. Ahí doy de alta la información importante, **sin los archivos adjuntos**. Verás que he creado 3 registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, he creado una tabla secundaria, llamada TABLA_ADJUNTOS, donde relaciono archivos adjuntos (1 por registro) a cada registro de la tabla MIS_REGISTROS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Merece la pena destacar que, mirando el pantallazo superior, podemos ver que PRIMER REGISTRO tiene asociados 3 archivos adjuntos, SEGUNDO REGISTRO tiene 2 y TERCER REGISTRO tiene 1 solamente.

Luego, nos creamos un formulario para la tabla MIS_ADJUNTOS. En mi caso, he borrado todos los campos del Detalle del formulario, salvo el control de los datos adjuntos. **IMPORTANTE**: He puesto como valor de la propiedad *Vista predeterminada* de este formulario **formularios continuos**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego me diseño el formulario principal, basado en la tabla MIS_REGISTROS. Y ahí, inserto como subformulario el formulario de los datos adjuntos, **vinculando los campos.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ya está. Con esto, veo todas las imágenes asociadas a cada registro de mi tabla MIS_REGISTROS. Por ejemplo, veamos el primer registro: (recordemos que tenía 3 archivos adjuntos):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ahora vamos a movernos al tercer registro (que tenía 1 archivo adjunto solamente):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta manera te podría permitir, de una manera sencilla y fácil, sin programación en VBA, mostrar las imágenes.

Tendrás que jugar con los tamaños y demás del formulario que uses como subformulario para poder encajar las 6 imágenes en pantalla, pero eso es tocar y probar.

Espero que pueda servirte de algo. Pero reitero en mi recomendación profesional al principio de la respuesta. Mejor usar hipervínculos a imágenes en carpetas de Windows que añadirlos como archivos adjuntos a la base.

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente texto está copiado directamente de la ayuda de Microsoft Office:

> 1. En el panel de navegación, haga clic con el botón secundario en el formulario o informe que desee cambiar y haga clic en Vista Diseño en el menú contextual.
> 2. En la ficha Diseño, en el grupo Herramientas, haga clic en Agregar campos existentes.
> 3. Aparecerá el panel Lista de campos, que incluye los campos de la tabla que proporcionan los datos para el formulario o informe. La lista representa los campos de datos adjuntos como expansibles (es decir, se puede hacer clic en el signo más o menos situado junto al campo).
> 4. La siguiente ilustración muestra un campo de datos adjuntos típico en el panel Lista de campos.
> 5. Un campo de datos adjuntos en el panel Lista de campos
> 6. Arrastre todo el campo de datos adjuntos desde la lista hasta el formulario (los elementos principal y secundario) y colóquelo en la ubicación que desee del formulario.
> 7. Access se ocupa de colocar un control de datos adjuntos en el formulario y de enlazar el control al campo de la tabla.
> 8. Si es preciso, haga clic con el botón secundario en el control y, a continuación, seleccione Propiedades para mostrar la hoja de propiedades del control. Establezca o cambie las propiedades del control para que se correspondan con el resto del formulario o informe.
> 9. Guarde los cambios y, a continuación, haga clic con el botón secundario en la pestaña de documento y haga clic en Vista Formulario o Vista Informe para abrir el formulario o el informe y verlo.
> 10. Si el campo subyacente contiene archivos de imágenes, el control representa esos archivos. Si el campo contiene otro tipo de archivo, como un documento de Word o una presentación de PowerPoint, el control muestra el icono correspondiente al tipo de archivo.

Puedes consultar toda la ayuda de datos tipo OLE en el siguente acceso:

[Ayuda objetos OLE Access](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Adjuntar-archivos-y-gr%C3%A1ficos-a-los-registros-de-una-base-de-datos-d40a09ad-a753-4a14-9161-7f15baad6dbd)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero no contesta a lo que pregunto. Mi idea es diseñar un formulario donde se puedan ver a la vez, por ejemplo, 6 imágenes de las que contenga el campo de datos adjuntos, Es decir, que de un registro de la tabla que contiene en su campo de datos adjuntos 6 imágenes, se puedan ver estas 6 a la vez en un formulario, a modo de ventana de explorador de Windows.